# Multiple USB connects-disconnects lead to USB port blackout

Tags: linux, usb

During the development of some software, we found out that the panel-pc we are using as a basis for it, behaves in a strange way during fast USB device connects-disconnects. This happens with any USB device (keyboard, flash drive, etc), which if I connect and disconnect it in a fast way (3-5 times in 3-4 seconds) then it causes the USB port to blackout.

Initially this happened really often even with if the plug-unplug sequences were slower. The manufacturer of the panel-pc claimed that it was some sort of a hardware issue, regarding a capacitor in the circuit. Indeed, the fixed devices showed a better stability, but the problem still seems to exist for fast paced plug-unplugs.

Eventually, the manufacturer claimed that this is normal, and it has to do with the USB port entering a STALL state. However, looking at the definition of the STALL state, doesn't seem the case to me, and I don't see how this can be connected with the issue I am facing.

Some extra info about the problem is the following:

- The panel-pc is running Ubuntu 16.04 w/ Kernel 4.1.15-2.0.0
- The port does not recover in any way other than power-cycling the
  panel-pc. Even soft reboot does not fix the issue.
- Rarely, the port does not recover even after power cycling the panel-pc
- Linux kernel message shows this during a port blackout:
  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCdwM.jpg)

Also, I've tried the same thing with a humble Raspberry Pi, which seems to be pretty fine with this kind of USB connection behavior.

So my question: what is the possible cause of that issue, and how can the USB STALL state be connected with it?

Comment: What kind of USB hardware is used in your host? Exactly please.

Comment: If I get the question right then the chip mentioned in the datasheet is USB2512B-AEZG